# Ruby SOAP with Savon 2 and nested attributes

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, hash, savon

My first time to work with SOAP.

Having looked into the Savon document but I couldn't figure out how to turn the following xml to hash. I'm using Savon 2.11.1.

Should I use ":attributes!" or "@" for the "version" and "language" attribute in the "fp:Example" element?

So, my question is how can I get this?

```
 <fp:Example version="1.0" language="en">
  <fp:FindSomething id="id-1">
      <fp:SomeStuff>
          <fp:Number>50</fp:Number>
      </fp:SomeStuff>
   </fp:FindSomething>
</fp:Example>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For version 2.11.1, @ is working with me. Find below an example

```
client.call(:create, {
:message => {
    :sObjects => {
      :'@xsi:type' => 'urn1:Contact',
      :FirstName => 'Jane',
      :LastName => 'Doe'
    }
  }
})
```

Yields:

```
<tns:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Contact">
  <tns:firstName>Jane</tns:firstName>
  <tns:lastName>Doe</tns:lastName>
</tns:sObjects>
```